# Does thomas-mcdonald / bootstrap-sass support the use of generators? Getting an error saying cannot find

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, sass

A simple question. Does this version support generators?

I wanted to test out using it and follow along with Ryan Bates screen cast which I uses a different version.

I've been playing with tables today and want to see how this works using the generator with a scaffold generated model and all its components.

Running rails g bootstrap:themed  returns

Could not find generator bootstrap:themed

So I tried to reinstall with rails g install:bootstrap

Error similar which lead me to try to find if it supports these commands.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't need generators for asset files, since we hook into the asset pipeline through the use of a Rails Engine - configuration options are available through the use of [variables](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html#variables) (use this as a reference, Sass variables are actually `$x` rather than `@x` and need to be defined *before* importing bootstrap), Sass' `@extend`, and Bootstrap's `@makeRow` and `@makeColumn` mixins, along with the other Bootstrap mixins.

Themed scaffold would be interesting but generally would be a pain to maintain - view scaffolding tends to get ripped apart pretty quickly anyway. Perhaps a 'sane' `application.html.erb` layout generator could be useful.

So yeah, we currently have no generators, don't need an asset one, themed scaffold probably not coming soon unless someone is interested enough to do the work on it, potentially a layout generator in the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the response Thomas. I had followed the railscast and it initially used a different gem which supported this. Later in another post or railscast your gem was mentioned and I've stuck with it since. However I needed to implement something in a quick manner so hoped using scaffolding and then generating would allow me to test and learn.

I'll lookout for the layout generator this sounds good.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout 
https://github.com/decioferreira/bootstrap-generators

Seems to be what you are asking for.

-Rick